# Additive and Bijective function on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

I was trying to solve the following functional equation:

$$f\big(f(x-y)\big)=f(x)-f(y)\text.$$

And I concluded that $f$ must be additive and bijective. The question is:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an additive bijective function. Is it true that $f$ has to be of the form $f(x)=cx$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?
>
> What if we impose the condition that $f\big(f(x)\big)=f(x)$. Is the identity map the only solution?

**Edit:** if $f$ is surjective and $f\big(f(x)\big)=f(x)$, then $f$ is the identity map (almost by definition).

Comment: Constant functions $F$ also satisfy $F\circ F=F$.

Comment: For what concerns the additive and bijective function, you'd like to read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation. For it to be bijective, just do this: take a basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ and make the function swap two elements of the basis, while being the identity on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are uncountably many *wild* additive bijections on $ \mathbb R $ (as @MarcoVergamini has indicated in a comment above), the original equation you encountered has only one injective/surjective solution: the identity function. It's straightforward to check that the identity function is a bijective solution. To see that it's the only injective/surjective solution, let $ x = y = 0 $ in
$$ f \big( f ( x - y ) \big) = f ( x ) - f ( y ) \tag { * } \label 0 $$
to get $ f \big( f ( 0 ) \big) = 0 $. Then, put $ x = f ( 0 ) $ and $ y = 0 $ in \eqref{0} to see that $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $. By setting $ y = 0 $ in \eqref{0} you have $ f \big( f ( x ) \big) = f ( x ) $. This means $ f ( x ) = x $ for every $ x $ in the range of $ f $. So, if $ f $ is supposed to be surjective, it follows that $ f $ must be the identity function. Also, if $ f $ is supposed to be injective, $ f \big( f ( x ) \big) = f ( x ) $ directly implies $ f ( x ) = x $ for all $ x $.

But there seems to be a problem with your claim that solutions of \eqref{0} must be bijective. Just similar to the construction of *wild* additive bijections, you can use a Hamel basis $ \mathcal H $ of $ \mathbb R $ over $ \mathbb Q $ to construct *wild* solutions of \eqref{0}: choose a nonempty subset $ \mathcal I $ of $ \mathcal H $, map every member of $ \mathcal I $ to itself and every member of $ \mathcal H \setminus \mathcal I $ to an arbitrary member of $ \mathcal I $, and finally extend this mapping linearly (over $ \mathbb Q $) to a function $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $. It's straightforward to check that this $ f $ will satisfy \eqref{0}. Therefore, unless any further restriction on $ f $ is given, it cannot be concluded solely from \eqref{0} that $ f $ must be injective/surjective.

But additivity of $ f $ is secured by \eqref{0}. $ f \big( f ( x ) \big) = f ( x ) $ can be used to rewrite \eqref{0} as $ f ( x - y ) = f ( x ) - f ( y ) $. Substituting $ x + y $ for $ x $ and rearranging the terms, that equation is transformed to the Cauchy functional equation. So, this part of your claim is definitely true.

Comment: Thans for your answer. Maybe I was missunderstood, the original problem (which I didn't write in my original post) had some hypotheses that allowed me to conclude that $f$ is biyective, it is not the case that I concluded that just from the functional equation

Comment: @alexp9 You're right. I've misunderstood you, in that case. But, as is noted in the first paragraph of my answer (and by yourself at the end of your post), having either injectivity or surjectivity of $ f $, the only solution of $ f \big( f ( x ) \big) = f ( x ) $ is trivially the identity function, regardless of other properties like additivity. What is your question in that case then?

Comment: I believe at that time I just wasn't able to see that conclusion right away.